# GridserachCV, make_scorer in python, for class specific F1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am working with a highly imbalanced dataset (more values in class 0 and few in class 1). To analyse the performance of the classifier I am using the F1 metric. I set average = None in the F1 function from scikitlearn, this is because I want to check its performance on class 0 and 1 separately and am only concerned about the classifier's performance on class 1.
 `value = f1_score(yTest, y_scores, average=None)`
`value[1] gives me the required value`

Now for hyperparameter tuning using gridserachcv, I create the F1 score in the following way
`f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, average=None)`
However this gives an array which is not accepted by `GridSearchCV(svc_clf, param_grid, cv=nfolds, error_score=0.0, scoring=f1_scorer2)`
How do I extract the value at index 1 to be used as the metric in the scoring parameter. This is because I want to place focus on the classifier's performance on class 1 during hyperparameter tuning.
I did try some naive ways of writing f1_scorer2[1] etc but it says *'_PredictScorer' object is not subscriptable*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only care about the f1 score for the positive class, then the defaults `average='binary'` and `pos_label=1` should be fine.

---

If you needed to in another situation, you should be able to define a thin wrapper function:

```py
def pos_f1_score(estimator, X, y):
    y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
    f1s = f1_score(y, y_pred, average=None)
    return f1s[1]
```

---

Finally, a number of common metrics have already been made into scorers that you can invoke with a string for `scorer`; see a list [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter).

Comment: is my understanding correct that this function pos_f1_score would be used in the following way:
```scored = make_scorer(pos_f1_score)

GridSearchCV(svc_clf, param_grid, cv=nfolds, error_score=0.0, scoring=scored )```

Comment: Since I defined the function to take an estimator, it already is formatted as a scorer, not a metric.  So no `make_scorer`, just `GridSearchCV(..., scoring=pos_f1_score)`.